# how to define a matrix and run a loop for multiple excel files in MATLAB?

Tags: excel, matlab, loops, filenames

I have more than 200 excel files with country names and years. I want Matlab to define the specific range of a specific sheet of these files as a matrix with headers (the code is written for an i-o table-matrix-) and run the code for each file  and save the output for each file in a separate file. The main problem is that I am not able to  process the files in a loop and define the matrix for each file at the same time. 
The code for a single file is the following

```
    function res=cb(a)
    a=[xlsread('aut2000.xls', 'domestic','B7:AV54')]
    a = a(any(a'),any(a))
    ...
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information regarding how you define the range in the excel files (i.e., whether there's a pattern to the ranges), it's hard to give specific advice, but the best way to do this would be to define the matrix in an array outside the loop, and then simply refer to the entry when in the loop:

```
files = {'file1.xls','file2.xls',...};
ranges = {'a7:d54','a6:f90',...};

function res=cb(files, ranges)

for n=1:length(files)
    a = xlsread(files{n}, 'domestic', ranges{n});
end
```

You could also link the structures (`files = {{'file1.xls','a4:c89'}, {'file2.xls','b7:d300'}, ...}`) and have the function loop through that structure.

Comment: thank you very much. But matlab creates an answer file for only the last file. How can I see the results of all files with their titles to distinguish them? thx again.

Comment: @user1153825 - No prob, if you think this answer was helpful please upvote it. I'm not sure what you're asking in the above comment... You can use the `disp` function to show data as you read it, in the `for` loop.

Comment: I mean MATLAB gives only one single output file for only one excel file as if I did not write a loop for the list of files. Therefore, the code works but I can not get what I want because the loop does not work. I would appreciate, if you could be more specific about disp function. Thx again.

Comment: I suggest you view the very expansive matlab help files, available at the matlab [website](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/disp.html) or by typing `help disp` or `doc disp` at your matlab prompt. Again, if this post has been helpful to you, please upvote it.